# How to combine two of list?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two list:

```
{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
```

and

```
{{1,1},{2,2}}
```

and I want my output is

```
{{1,2,3,1,1},{1,2,3,2,2},{4,5,6,1,1},{4,5,6,2,2},{7,8,9,1,1},{7,8,9,2,2}}
```

I have tried outlist, but it doesn't what i want.

Comment: If you show what you have tried, then people can help you fix it. Using `Outer`, all you need is `Flatten[Outer[Join, list1, list2, 1], 1]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coolwater's use of `Tuples` is cleaner here, but another option:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};

b = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};

Join @@ Outer[Join, a, b, 1]
```

Should you happen to want sublists like this it will be useful:

```
Outer[Join, a, b, 1]

Transpose[%]
```

> ```
> {{{1, 2, 3, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 2, 2}},
>  {{4, 5, 6, 1, 1}, {4, 5, 6, 2, 2}},
>  {{7, 8, 9, 1, 1}, {7, 8, 9, 2, 2}}}
>
> {{{1, 2, 3, 1, 1}, {4, 5, 6, 1, 1}, {7, 8, 9, 1, 1}},
>  {{1, 2, 3, 2, 2}, {4, 5, 6, 2, 2}, {7, 8, 9, 2, 2}}}
> ```

See documentation for [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html), [`Join`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html), [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html), [`Out`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Out.html).

Answer (score 6):

Also:

```
Distribute[{a, b}, List, List, List, Join]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 2, 2}, {4, 5, 6, 1, 1}, {4, 5, 6, 2, 
>     2}, {7, 8, 9, 1, 1}, {7, 8, 9, 2, 2}}

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Tuples`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tuples.html):

```
Join @@@ Tuples[{##}] &[{{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 2}}]
```

> {{1, 2, 3, 1, 1}, {1, 2, 3, 2, 2}, {4, 5, 6, 1, 1}, {4, 5, 6, 2, 
>     2}, {7, 8, 9, 1, 1}, {7, 8, 9, 2, 2}}

Answer (score 3):

You should implement something like this:

```
a = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
b = {{1, 1}, {2, 2}};
Table[Table[Flatten[{a[[j]], b[[i]] }], {i, 1, Length[b]}], {j, 1, 
  Length[a]}]
```